# Java Regex for formal Logic format

Tags: java, regex, format, logic

Im looking to match a string to the format of an expression in formal logic, where two alphabetic characters are operated on by v|^|>|=, where the characters can be preceded by ~|!|?, and where the characters maybe be surrounded by brackets and preceded again by ~|!|?. At first I thought that the following expression might do it:

```
 s.matches("^[!?~]*[(]*[!?~]*[a-z]{1}\\s[v>=^]{1}\\s[!?~]*[a-z]{1}[)]*$")
```

However, I have realised that these expressions can be stacked onto one another, and I dont know how to account for that in the regex.

Examples of acceptable matches:

~p v q

~?(p ^ ~r)

!p

p v ~(!r ^ t)

~!(p = (~!q ^ t))

It is possible to add as many operators as you want, to create an enormously long expression. How do I account for this with the regex in a general format?

Thanks heaps :)

Comment: FTLOG why?  FWIW, I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't fully describe that language with a plain regular expression. The problem is that any letter can be replaced by an expression.  You need recursive regular expressions, and these aren't supported by Java's `java.util.regex` package.

This is a feature that, as far as I know, started in Perl 4 or so and has appeared in a few package that advertise "Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions" (PCRE).  It's not part of standard Java, Python, Ruby, C++, and I don't believe the .NET libraries for C#, VB.Net, C++/CLI etc. have it either.